# Application crashes while saving core data in iOS11

Tags: objective-c, ios11

Works perfectly in iOS 10. After I updated my iOS to iOS11 the application is crashing while saving data to core data with an exception.
I have used RZVinyl framework for coredata

```
BOOL isSaved = [currentContext save:&saveErr];
```

> Assertion failed: (moreParameters->mostRecentEntry ==
>    CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(stack, stackCount - 1)), function
>    NSKeyValuePopPendingNotificationPerThread, file
>    /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1444.12/EO.subproj/NSKeyValueObserving.m, line 933.
>
> ```
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00000001826fd348 __pthread_kill + 8
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000182811354 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x000000018266cfd8 abort + 140
> 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x0000000182640abc basename_r + 0
> 4   Foundation                        0x00000001834f1a9c -[NSRunLoop+ 178844 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 0
> 5   Foundation                        0x00000001834df538 NSKeyValueDidChange + 436
> 6   Foundation                        0x0000000183597ae4 NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 140
> 7   CoreData                          0x00000001854107c8 -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 120
> 8   CoreData                          0x0000000185416358 -[NSManagedObject+ 844632 (_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 692
> 9   CoreData                          0x000000018542e054 -[NSManagedObjectContext+ 942164 (_NestedContextSupport) _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 652
> 10  CoreData                          0x000000018542e4bc -[NSManagedObjectContext+ 943292 (_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 804
> 11  CoreData                          0x000000018542f3f0 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext+ 947184 (_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 580
> 12  CoreData                          0x0000000185431644 internalBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 92
> 13  libdispatch.dylib                 0x0000000182569048 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
> 14  libdispatch.dylib                 0x0000000182571ae8 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
> 15  CoreData                          0x000000018541dd10 _perform + 232
> 16  CoreData                          0x000000018542f0e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext+ 946404 (_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 172
> 17  CoreData                          0x0000000185387ff8 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 2580
> ```

```
NSManagedObjectContext *currentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[[currentContext userInfo] setObject:self forKey:kRZCoreDataStackParentStackKey];

[self performBlock:^{
    BOOL hasChanges = [currentContext hasChanges];
    if ( !hasChanges) {
        RZVLogInfo(@"Managed object context %@ does not have changes, not saving", self);
        rzv_performSaveCompletionAsync(completion, nil);
        return;
    }

    NSError *saveErr = nil;
    BOOL isSaved = [currentContext save:&saveErr];
    if ( !isSaved) {
        RZVLogError(@"Error saving managed object context context %@: %@", self, saveErr);
        rzv_performSaveCompletionAsync(completion, saveErr);

    }      
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing right now and was looking for an answer when I came across your question.

Without any answers to be found I did some in-depth investigation and found the cause (at least in my case).

It turned out that one of the object's relationships was observing KV changes to update the object regarding changes to it's values, and it was also updating a change to the value of the relationship.

That triggered and update on the Object, which caused the relationship to updated with a change, and so on and so forth...

This recursion in KVO caused a crash.

Make sure that if you are observing changes via `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` to update your relationship regarding this change, don't update if the observer is the one being set.

Does that make sense for you?

Let me know if this is the case and you need a code sample to understand this very confusing answer.

**UPDATE:**

I know my answer is quite confusing and vague, so I'll add an example.

Consider the following. 
We have two example classes which has relationship to each other (i.e reverse relationship):

```
class A: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var b: B!

    override func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
        b?.willChangeValue(forKey: "a")
    }

    override func didChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.didChangeValue(forKey: key)
        b?.didChangeValue(forKey: "a")
    }
}

class B: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var date: Date?
    @NSManaged var a: A!

    override func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
        a?.willChangeValue(forKey: "b")
    }

    override func didChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        super.didChangeValue(forKey: key)
        a?.didChangeValue(forKey: "b")
    }

    func setNewA(_ newA: A) {
        newA.b = self
        a = newA
    }
}
```

We use `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` in each class to notify it's relationship regarding changes in itself.

Now consider the following code:

```
let b = B(context: context)
let a = A(context: context)
b.setNewA(a)
```

We use the `setNewA` function to set the reverse reference.
In the function, first `b` assigns itself to `a.b` for the reverse reference and then sets `self.a` reference.
At this point, `a` already knows about `b`.

The later will cause `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` on `b` to be called (as we set `a`). Then `a` will pick up the update and notify `b`.

From here on, try can guess how it continues.

This was pretty much what happened to me, with a few minor differences.

I overrode these functions because I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and I needed to pick up on changes in the relationships to update my UI.

It threw me in a loop that caused the crash.

At the end, the fix was rather simple. `A` was modified to be:

```
override func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
    guard key != "b" else { return }
    b?.willChangeValue(forKey: "a")
}

override func didChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.didChangeValue(forKey: key)
    guard key != "b" else { return }
    b?.didChangeValue(forKey: "a")
}
```

and `B` was modified the same way, to be:

```
override func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
    guard key != "a" else { return }
    a?.willChangeValue(forKey: "b")
}

override func didChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
    super.didChangeValue(forKey: key)
    guard key != "a" else { return }
    a?.didChangeValue(forKey: "b")
}
```

This prevents each from updating the other once the relationship itself is set (which is redundant, as each is already notified once one of it's properties is set), thus breaking the cycle.

Again, this was the case on my end and this is what fixed it.
Don't know if you're experiencing the issue due to the same reason, but hopefully it'll give you an idea where to look.

Hope it's easier to understand now.

If you're still having trouble understanding, share some code or contact me directly and I'll try and help.

Comment: This is very close to project. Using them in lot many places.  Can I have some sample code which fixed your error.

Comment: This is very close to project. Using them in lot many places.  Can I have some sample code which fixed your error and also can you re- phrase   "Make sure that if you are observing changes via willChangeValue and didChangeValue to update your relationship regarding this change, don't update if the observer is the one being set." Its bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oren. Your example was clear and solved my issue.

Comment: No problem, happy it helped.